# Hide div after click of button with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to hide a 'div' after a button is clicked. I don't want to use .remove() because when you refresh the app it comes back. I have the information about this div on the database and I wanna work with it.

I tried already creating an Ajax call to select the information that I'm looking at and then on the front-end I'm telling if it exist then delete it. But I feel like I'm missing something and I don't know why.

Frontend:

```
$('#deletePromo').on('click', function(res){
    let success = function(res){
        if (eventName && customerID){
            $(`#promotion-container .promo${i}`).remove();
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/promotions-done',
            crossDomain: true,
            //success: success,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                customerID : customerID,
                eventName : eventName,
            }
        }).done(function(res){
            console.log('res', res)
            if (res != null){
                $(`#promotion-container .promo${i}`).remove();
                //$(`#promotion-container .promo${i}`).css('display', 'none')
            }
        })
        })
})
```

Backend:

```
router.post('/promotions-done', function(req, res) {
  let customerID = req.user.customer_id
  let restaurantGroupId = req.user.restaurant_group_id
  let eventName = req.body.eventName

  db.task(t => {
      return t.any(`SELECT * FROM promotions_redemption WHERE (customer_id = '${customerID}' AND event_name = '${eventName}' AND restaurant_group_id = ${restaurantGroupId})`).then(function(promotionsDone) {
        return res.json({'promotionsDone': promotionsDone})
      })
      .catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err)
      })
    })
})
```

What I'm trying to do here is saying if the customerID and eventName already exist on the table then remove div from the person. I don't have much experience working with backend so is there a way to tell the program to check the database for this information and if it exists then remove the div.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you need to check the response of the ajax call by adding a .done call to the ajax request on the frontend. You could do this by adding `.done(function( msg ) {
    //Do something with msg variable with response
  });
`

Comment: There is an example here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#example-0

Comment: Thanks, I added the .done and I'm getting the correct response from the AJAX call. If I click the button the card goes away as I want to but if I refresh the webpage then the card is back. It's not saving the information :(

Comment: I edited it btw, so you can see how I added a .done()

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some HTML in a template file, or in the database that has the button there to start with.  Since your AJAX code will only run when the button is clicked, you will need to either do 1 of 2 things:

1. Add an AJAX call on page load
2. Handle looking for the button and hide/show it in your templating language/platform (think asp.net, python django, php laravel etc) to avoid the AJAX request.

Since we don't know your platform, I will show you option 1

First, I would change the initial state of your HTML to NOT show the button by default.  This would look something like this:

```html
<div id="promotion-container">
    <button class="promo" style="display: none" />
</div>
```

Otherwise you will have the button be shown for the amount of time the AJAX request takes.

Next, you will want to add this function call to the page.  I have reversed the login in the done function to "show" the button or unhide it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let success = function(res){
        if (eventName && customerID){
            $(`#promotion-container .promo${i}`).remove();
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/promotions-done',
            crossDomain: true,
            //success: success,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                customerID : customerID,
                eventName : eventName,
            }
        }).done(function(res){
            console.log('res', res)
            if (res === null){
                //$(`#promotion-container .promo${i}`).remove();
                $(`#promotion-container .promo${i}`).css('display', 'block')
            }
        })
        })
})
```

Comment: This is good but I don't know if it would be the best solution because I'm already showing this button in just some of the cards, so I already have conditionals over this button. Also, I already kind of tried this and when I refresh it starts from zero, it's like if it forgets that it has the information already.

Comment: The web is stateless.  Meaning it doesn't remember what happened previously.  So, when a user refreshes the page, the browser needs to load state, think of it as recalling the data.  So in other words, that refresh flushes the data away, and starts over each time.  Making the browser "forget" each time you refresh.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is why my card keeps appearing, reading more into it apparently I need to save the button state in the server side. I'm still pretty new into this so if my code is already saving information on the database and then checking it I don't understand why isn't being saved. Any help would be amazing! :( 
Thanks for the information btw!! :)

Comment: Without knowing how your html is rendered, or how the data being displayed through html, it sounds like there isn't any answer that would be very helpful.  But speaking in generalities, you are right with your last comment, if you save the state of the button, and render your button based off of that state, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The easiest solution to your problem would be to use a client-side cookie.  If you don't have a cookie package already, I'd recommend [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).</s>

On your html page:

```
<div id="promotion-container" hidden> //you want it hidden by default
//if it is shown by default there will be an annoying screen flicker when the pages loads

<script src="/path/to/js.cookie.js"></script>
```

On jQuery page:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    if (!Cookies.get('name1') || !Cookies.get('name2')) {
       $('#promotion-container').show();
    };

    Cookies.set('name1', customerId, {expires:14} ); //must include expiration else the cookie will expire when the browser closes.
    Cookies.set('name2', eventName, {expires:14} ); //you might need to make an eventId if eventName is too large       
});
```

The second input for `Cookies.set` is the `'value'` for the cookie.  if `'value' = null`, then `Cookies.get('name') = null`.

This is assuming you already have the means to set `customerId` and `eventName` for each user.  Also you might need to modify where the Cookies are set based on when the customerId is created on the page.

### EDIT:

There are 2 ways you can run a query the way you describe, both of which won't work they way you want *unless* you use a session cookie.

**1)** You have `res.render` inside of a query.

This would ensure the `div` is never shown to a user that has already clicked on it, but would significantly hurt your site's performance.  The query would run every time the page is rendered, regardless of whether or not the client has a customerId.  Your site would would be painfully slow with a large amount of traffic.

**2)** You run a POST request through client-side js with ajax and compare the customerId with your db; if a result is found, you remove the div.

This would function the way you want it to, and wouldn't hurt performance, but nothing is stopping a customer from using something like [burp](https://portswigger.net/burp) to intercept the POST request. They could change the data argument to whatever they want and make sure the div loads for them.

The only solution to these problems that I see would be to validate a user when they click on the div AND on the server with a session cookie. (for user validation I use [passport](http://www.passportjs.org) and [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)).

I can show you how I set this up, but to make it specific to your needs I would need to know more about how your site is setup.

PS I misunderstood why you needed to hide the div, and using a client-side cookie would be a terrible idea in hindsight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I don't wanna use cookies because if the user clears them, the card would appear again and they would be able to redeem the card again and I want it to be gone forever once they click it :(

Comment: How is the customerId created?

Comment: They create an account, so I have the information on the database. So now when they click on the button of that card I get information of them on the database as to what card they used, and the card disappears but it appears again in reload because the site is not saving the state of the button or reading the information.

Comment: Are users able to access the `div page` without signing up?

Comment: Also I'm about to post an edit explaining why these questions are relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! and No, the users are not able to see this page without an account, so they would always have a customerID. So its a page that have different cards, but just some of them have this button, once they click it  they can not use the card again, so this is why I know if I use cookies or session storage and they remove them, the card would appear again as the app would forget that the button was clicked. I know I need to save the state of the button and check with window.onload, but I struggle a little with backend so I'm still trying to figure this out :(